# Can a temporary (mut'ah) marriage be conducted between two non-Muslims?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

Wikipedia's article on [Nikah mut'ah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut%E2%80%98ah#Similarities) mentions that like a permanent marriage, it can't be conducted between a Muslim male and a non-Abrahmic-religion female, or between a non-Muslim male and a Muslim female.

Can it be conducted between a non-Muslim male and a non-Muslim female?

Comment: why should a non-Muslim male and a non-Muslim female care about Islam laws about marriage? they can marry based on their own religion or laws. this question is off-topic here.

Comment: it does seem somewhat odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) of [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) it is permitted.

According to Islam any human potentially has duty to research about existence of God and then about religion and and if do a real and serious research will finally become a Muslim. because in fact God exists and currently the only accepted religion in view of God is Islam. although Judaism was accepted before prophet Jesus (PBUH) and Christianity was accepted before Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) but they are not accepted today because they are deviated today and Islam is sent by God as a perfect and updated religion.

In Islamic view if a couple marry according to their own religion they are considered married and couple in Islam view although they are not Muslim. this means that for example if a non Muslim married couple convert to Islam their marriage is considered legal and there is no new marriage needed based on Islamic rules.

A non-Muslim male and a non-Muslim female can marry based on their own religion and laws and this marriage is considered legal in Islam if their own religion consider it legal.

---

**References:**

[Online answering](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/?p=oas) of [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi](http://www.makarem.ir/)

Comment: Could a Muslim, possibly religiously qualified, deliver a sermon to "counsel and guide the couple"?  ("counsel and guide is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam#Background), though apparently it is not mandatory for a [temporary marriage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut‘ah) "it can be done ... with God as witness".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm why not? there is no problem in that.